# How to make the select2 work with all unicode keywords?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm having a  tag with some options which theirs text is unicode string. More clearly, it's Vietnamese string, then i search with the searchbox of select2, it does not return the result as i expected.

For example, the select2 has an Buổi sáng, when i type in search box "sang" it does not return the option above. Maybe i have to use the matcher of select2 but i don't know where to approach it, please help me.

```
<select class="select2">
    <option value="o1">Buổi sáng</option>
    <option value="o2">Buổi trưa</option>
    <option value="o3">Buổi chiều</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is the search box?

Comment: @randomSoul It's automatically created by the Select2 plugin

Answer (score 0):

It does work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="o1">Buổi sáng</option>
  <option value="o2">Buổi trưa</option>
  <option value="o3">Buổi chiều</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think it's not working with select2 version 3.4.5 :|

Comment: I know where is the problem, it comes from ui-select of angularjs, not from select2() :(